# Рекурсивный метод в java. Откуда берется ответ, если он просто сам себя возвращает?

Tags: java, рекурсия

Хочу понять как система понимает, что нужно вывести на экране значение 4? Этот метод высчитывает  наибольший общий делитель, **НО**  ***как  система понимает, как вывести результат на экран***? Ведь вариантов результата этого метода может быть только два на мой взгляд, это: 1) Переменная P   2) Этот же самый метод gcd(int p, int q)

```
public class GCD {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(gcd(4, 8));
        }

        public static int gcd(int p, int q)
        {
            if (q == 0) return p;
            int r = p % q;
            return gcd(q, r);
        }

    }
```

*ВЫВОД*: **4**

Comment: Вы лучше не вопрос о Java задевайте, а в принципе почитайте про рекурсивные методы, чтобы сложить у себя в голове более точное понимание о них. По поводу Вашего пункта 2: возвращается-то не метод, а его результат

Comment: Спасибо,  согласен с вами, что нужно больше прочитать про рекурсивные методы, но можете более подробно описать как выводится число 4 ?

Comment: `(4, 8)` -> 8 != 0 => `(8, 4 % 8)` -> 4 != 0 => `(4, 8 % 4)` => 0 == 0 => `4`

Comment: (4, 8 % 4) => 0 == 0 =>  4     .  Мне вот этот момент не понятен.  Если метод возвращает 0, то почему в итоге выходит 4?

Comment: метод возвращает не ноль, а значение р, которое при q = 0, имеет значение 4 в данном случае. при следующей итерации на место локальной переменной метода р подставляется рассчитанное значение r, то есть р = r.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcd(4,8)
q = 8 и != 0 =>
r = остаток от деления 4/8 = 4
gcd(8, 4)
q = 4 != 0 =>
r = 8 % 4 = 0 (остаток от деления 8 на 4 = 0)
gcd(4, 0)
q = 0! => return p(а p = 4 в последней итерации)